# Python unexpected output in for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I have a JSON file with a config  `schedules.json` which contains information about a pattern and a pair of users as such:

```
{
    "pattern": [
        [2, "john", "jane"],
        [2, "sam", "bob"],
        [3, "john", "jane"],
        [2, "sam", "bob"],
        [2, "john", "jane"],
        [3, "sam", "bob"]
    ]
}
```

The idea is that for the number found in the first index, a json object will be created for each user in this list for the number of times found in the number. i.e: 
for a pattern `[2,"john","jane"]`, a json object for `john` and `jane` will be created 2 times each. 
for a pattern `[3,"john","jane"]`, a json object for `john` and `jane` will be created 3 times each etc...

The python code is below:

```
shift_rota = []

schedule_layers_template = {
    "morning_user": "",
    "night_user": ""
}

# Load the schedules config file
with open('config/schedules.json') as f:
    
    schedules = json.load(f)
    
    for pattern in schedules['pattern']:
                    
        # Get the number of occurrences
        occurence = int(pattern[0])
        
        # Remove occurence from list
        pattern.pop(0)
        
        morning_shift_user = pattern[0]
        night_shift_user = pattern[1]
        
        for _ in range(0, occurence):
            
            my_template = schedule_layers_template
        
            my_template['morning_user'] = morning_shift_user
            
            # Append schedule layer to list
            shift_rota.append(my_template)
        
            my_template['night_user'] = night_shift_user
            
            # Append schedule layer to list
            shift_rota.append(my_template)
            
print(f"Final shift rota {shift_rota}")
```

The problem here is that the final output is returning this:

```
Final shift rota [{'morning_user': 'sam', 'night_user': 'bob'}, {'morning_user': 'sam', 'night_user': 'bob'}, {'morning_user': 'sam', 'night_user': 'bob'}, {'morning_user': 'sam', 'night_user': 'bob'}, {'morning_user': 'sam', 'night_user': 'bob'}, {'morning_user': 'sam', 'night_user': 'bob'}, {'morning_user': 'sam', 'night_user': 'bob'}, {'morning_user': 'sam', 'night_user': 'bob'}, {'morning_user': 'sam', 'night_user': 'bob'}, {'morning_user': 'sam', 'night_user': 'bob'}, {'morning_user': 'sam', 'night_user': 'bob'}, {'morning_user': 'sam', 'night_user': 'bob'}, {'morning_user': 'sam', 'night_user': 'bob'}, {'morning_user': 'sam', 'night_user': 'bob'}, {'morning_user': 'sam', 'night_user': 'bob'}, {'morning_user': 'sam', 'night_user': 'bob'}, {'morning_user': 'sam', 'night_user': 'bob'}, {'morning_user': 'sam', 'night_user': 'bob'}, {'morning_user': 'sam', 'night_user': 'bob'}, {'morning_user': 'sam', 'night_user': 'bob'}, {'morning_user': 'sam', 'night_user': 'bob'}, {'morning_user': 'sam', 'night_user': 'bob'}, {'morning_user': 'sam', 'night_user': 'bob'}, {'morning_user': 'sam', 'night_user': 'bob'}, {'morning_user': 'sam', 'night_user': 'bob'}, {'morning_user': 'sam', 'night_user': 'bob'}, {'morning_user': 'sam', 'night_user': 'bob'}, {'morning_user': 'sam', 'night_user': 'bob'}]
```

The final output is repeating the user sam and bob for some reasons. Can someone please help ?

Comment: `my_template = schedule_layers_template` this is not creating a copy of `schedule_layers_template`. It's just using the same `dict` on every iteration.

Comment: How do i create a copy?

Comment: `my_template = schedule_layers_template.copy()` should work.

Comment: Or `my_template = dict(schedule_layers_template)`

Comment: It's still not working. This time it is taking only the last value from the list. (Jane and Bob). Sam and john are not seen at all in the final output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by using `deepcopy`. Sample code below:

```
import copy

...

with open('schedules.json') as f:
schedules = json.load(f)
for pattern in schedules['pattern']:
    # Get the number of occurrences
    occurence = int(pattern[0])
    # Remove occurence from list
    pattern.pop(0)
    morning_shift_user = pattern[0]
    night_shift_user = pattern[1]
    for _ in range(0, occurence):
        my_template = copy.deepcopy(schedule_layers_template)
        my_template['morning_user'] = morning_shift_user
        my_template['night_user'] = night_shift_user
        # Append schedule layer to list
        shift_rota.append(my_template)
print(f"Final shift rota {shift_rota}")
```

Answer (score 0):

PFB modified code which is working fine.

Here, we should create a copy of schedule_layers_template and then assign it to my_template.

```
import json


shift_rota = []
schedule_layers_template = {
    "morning_user": "",
    "night_user": ""
}
# Load the schedules config file
with open('schedules.json') as f:
    schedules = json.load(f)
    for pattern in schedules['pattern']:
        # Get the number of occurrences
        occurence = int(pattern[0])
        # Remove occurence from list
        pattern.pop(0)
        morning_shift_user = pattern[0]
        night_shift_user = pattern[1]
        for _ in range(0, occurence):
            my_template = schedule_layers_template.copy()
            my_template['morning_user'] = morning_shift_user
            my_template['night_user'] = night_shift_user
            # Append schedule layer to list
            shift_rota.append(my_template)
print(f"Final shift rota {shift_rota}")
```

Comment: It's still not working. This time it is taking only the last value from the list. (Jane and Bob). Sam and john are not seen at all in the final output

Comment: Can you please share your desired/required output ? @MervinHemaraju

Comment: I've already solved it using copy.deepcopy(). I shared my answer above. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid issues of having to copy it would be easier to move the template into the for loop and run

```
shift_rota = []
with open('schedules.json') as f:
    
    schedules = json.load(f)
    
    for pattern in schedules['pattern']:
        
        # Get the number of occurrences
        occurence = int(pattern[0])
        
        for _ in range(0,occurence):
            
            schedule_layers_template = {
                "morning_user": pattern[1],
                "night_user": pattern[2]
            }
            shift_rota.append(schedule_layers_template)
        
            
            
pprint(shift_rota)
```